# How to upload a file in laravel using jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, validation, laravel-5

The picture must be an image and of file type: jpg, jpeg. I get these error messages even though I'm uploading a valid jpg or jpeg file. I'm trying to achieve user profile picture update, the column already exists but it's nullable whenever they sign in.

Now, I am trying to update the profile picture field and some other fields. The other fields are working but when I tried to update the image as well, I get error message such as "The picture must be an image" or "The picture must be a file of type: jpg, jpeg".

Initially I used jquery onChange method to get the file input whenever it changes, then I trimmed it using the `this.value.replace(/^C:\\fakepath\\/i, '')`, then I passed this trimmed value in to my ajax function as data

Trimming the file input , initially it is empty.. but I trim it whenever it changes

```
            var path = '';
            $('.file').on("change", function(){ 
               path = this.value.replace(/^C:\\fakepath\\/i, '');
               $('#fake_btn').text(path);
             });
```

then I pass it to my ajax

```
                   $.ajax({
                        async: true,
                        url: "/user/update_profile",
                        method: 'POST',
                        data: { picture:path,about: $('#about').val(),fb: $('#facebook').val(),tw: $('#twitter').val(),ln: $('#linkendin').val() },
                        success:function(data){
                            if(data['errors']){
                                const ex = data.errors;
                                $('.warning').html('');
                                $('.alert-message').hide();
                                $.each(ex,function(key,value){
                                    $('.alert-message').show();
                                    $('.warning').append('<p>'+value+'</p>');
                                });
                            }else{
                                $('.warning').html('');
                                $('.alert-message').hide();
                                $('.alert-success').fadeIn();
                                $('.success').html(data.message);
                            }
                            $('#update-profile').html('Update');
                            $('#update-profile').hide();
                            $('#loader-icon').fadeOut();
                        }
                    });
```

Here is what my controller looks like

```
    public function update(Request $request){
        $image = "";
            $attribute = Validator::make($request->all(),[
                'picture' => 'image|mimes:jpg,jpeg|max:2048|nullable',
                'about' => 'min:20',
                'fb' => 'min:20|nullable',
                'tw' => 'min:20|nullable',
                'ln' => 'min:20|nullable'
            ]);
            if($attribute->fails()){
                $error = array('errors'=>$attribute->errors());
                return Response()->json($error);
            }
            if(empty($request->picture)){
                $image = 'Null';
            }else{
                $image = $request->picture;
                $image = rand() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $image->move(public_path('user_images'), $image);
            }
            $user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);
            $user->about = $request->about;
            $user->image = $image;
            $user->save();
            $fb = empty($request->fb) ? 'Null' : $request->fb;
            $tw = empty($request->tw) ? 'Null' : $request->tw;
            $ln = empty($request->ln) ? 'Null' : $request->ln;

        $userSocialExist = Social::usersocialExist(Auth::user()->id);
            if($userSocialExist){
                $social = Social::where([
                    ['user_id', Auth::user()->id]
                ])->update(['facebook' => $fb,'twitter' => $tw,'linkendin'=>$ln]);
                $data = array('message'=>'social updated!');
                return Response()->json($data); 
            }else{
                $social = new Social();
                $social->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
                $social->facebook = $fb;
                $social->twitter = $tw;
                $social->linkendin = $ln;
                $social->save();
                $data = array('message'=>'social created!');
                return Response()->json($data); 
            }
```

Please note that I'm updating the user's social media links on the same page, but it works well when updating their social media links only. I get these error messages only when trying to update the image.

Comment: it seems youi dont actually upload an image file, rather you send a path only. This is not what you expect

Comment: i feel so too, can you suggest a better solution to me

Comment: actualy upload the image using [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) that can handle files and passing formData in jquery.ajax.data and then using laravel documentation on how to handle uploaded files

Comment: Thanks for your response, but the point now is, is there way to check if the input file has no value in jquery before procedding to my controller?  because what I'm currently doint is if path == '' then i have a similar ajax call to what i posted but it doesn't have the path processed ...i hope you understand what I'm saying

Comment: yes you can check documentation of formdata and <input type="file">

Comment: Use FormData to process your form, don't forget to set the enctype to multipart/form-data

Comment: I'm using form data now... But i still get TypeError: Argument 1 of FormData.contructor does not implement interface form data .  Why am i getting this...can anyone just help me with sample send a file and atleat an input type of text . Thank you